# Get Add-in File Paths from VS 2008, programatically

Tags: visual-studio-2008, scripting, path, add-in

How can I get the Add-in File paths in Visual Studio 2008, programatically using C# and too scripting like BAT files ?

Add-in File paths appears in:

**Tools option menu -> Options -> Environment -> Add-in/Macros Security**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get read/write the Add-in file paths from the registry, this is the key (VS2008) :

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\9.0\AutomationOptions\LookInFolders